# symfony2 : what make a request a MasterRequest in UnitTests

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I have a phenomenon: 
I have a Listener, which is creating a closure in onKernelRequest, if it is a MasterRequest. I check if the request I am dealing with is a MasterRequest to avoid running this closure several times.

When I run the code in the browser everything is fine and behaves like intended. However if I run it with phpunit in a functional test using a WebTestCase two test cases behave like in the browser, but the third one never comes in as a MasterRequest and therefore in the test my code is never passed.

Has someone more insight on what makes a request a MasterRequest? Has it to do with the routing? The third case, which is causing the problem is using / with get parameters, while the others rely on the common routing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not about Request, but about `HttpKernelInterface`

Check out the code at [github](https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/master/HttpKernelInterface.php). The kernel either treats each request as a master request or as a sub-request. So it's up to kernel.

Probably in your tests in two cases you create a new kernel, but in a third one it's an existing one. It's just a guess, you should probably just debug it.

Comment: The interesting question is, why the behaviour differ between test and real life use. 
That it is either a master request or a subrequest is obvious. With debugging we found this to be the reason for skipping the code.